# Target Range.End with blanks

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell, target

I know this is a common question but i tried multiple solutions but none worked as my need.

I need to store the first cell of a column with a few blank rows using Target as my code is used for Worksheet_Change, for example:

Column

**1**

(blank)

2

3

(blank)

4

5(My Target)

In this example I need to store  number 1 in variable.(Nfirst =1)

At first i tried Target.End(xlUp) but because of blank cells it does not return 1.
My guess is I need to use Target.Column.. something but tried in many different ways and none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after many possibilities.
Solution:

Cells(1, target.Column)